# How to iterate over 2 hashmap for same key and add key and both values to object

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm learning on collections and I wanted to use the streams to loop through 2 `HashMap` and add the key and both values to `List` object.

Eg:

```java
HashMap<String, String> map1= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> map2= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

map1.put("A", "Apple");
map1.put("B", "Ball");
map1.put("C", "Cucumber");
map1.put("D", "Dairy");

map2.put("A", "Airplane");
map2.put("B", "Baby");
map2.put("C", "Cat");
map2.put("D", "Dog");
```

```java
class DummyClass {
    
    String Key;
    String Value1;
    String Value2;

    // getters and setters..
}
```

```java
List<DummyClass> test = Add key, and both Values
```

**Output Expectations** :

```
DummayClass Obj1 = {A,Apple,Airplane};
DummayClass Obj2 = {B,Ball,Baby}; likewise
```

I can achieve this over iterating individual maps and comparing the key's and adding it. But I would like to achieve the same using `Streams`.

Comment: Can you share with us the places you tried and stuck with?

Comment: No matter if formally homework or self-study I think that this applies: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any method to iterate over two HashMaps simultaneously but you could do something like this:

```
List<DummyClass> objects = 
    map1.entrySet().stream().map(object -> {
        return new DummyClass(object.getKey(), object.getValue(), map2.get(object.getKey()));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This maps all key value pairs from map1 to new instances of the DummyClass while picking the value with the same key from map2.
As Ole V.V. correctly said you should add a check to see if the key from map1 is  actually a valid key in map2.

Note that you have to add a constructor to your DummyClass for this code to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the entry set of `map1`. A stream operation is fine. For each entry, check if the key is also in `map2` (use the `filter` method of your stream). If it is, create a `DummyClass` object from the key and the values from both maps.

PS Also in your `DummyClass` respect the Java naming conventions. Instance variable names begin with small letters, so `key`, `value1` and `value2`. Also write a constructor for the class.

Tutorial link: [Iterate over a Map in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-iterate-map) (with a section on using the Stream API)

Documentation links:

- [`Map.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entrySet())
- `Map.Entry.getKey()`
- [`Map.containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))
- [`Map.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

Define a record to hold results.

```
record Combo ( String k , String x , String y ) {}
```

Make a stream of the entries from the first map. From each entry extract the key and value. Pass those to constructor of our combo class, along with a third argument which is the value from second map accessed by key from first map.

Here is some untested code to try.

```
List< Combo } combos = mapX.entrySet().stream().map( entry -> new Combo( entry.getKey() , entry.getValue() , mapY.get( entry.getKey() ) ) ).toList() ;
```